# If berserk characters are incapacitated, are they still berserk?

Tags: savage-worlds

When a character with the Berserk edge gets damage, they become berserk if they fail a Smarts roll. They stay in that state until they spend a round doing nothing, which allows them to make a Smarts roll at -2 to stop being berserk.

What happens if a berserk character is incapacitated? Does the berserk state stop because of the incapacitation?

Or, from another point of view, what happens if a character is incapacitated with a single blow (4+ wounds)? Do they roll to see if they become berserk? Does the incapacitation prevent the berserk state from "activating"?

This has several implications. For example, does the character ignore wound penalties for the Vigor roll to see if they die or get an injury? If they are down because of one single blow and then recover (e.g. because of Healing), are they berserk?

Answer (score 4):

[Clint answers this question](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40366&view=next&sid=2cdcb0dc419351a5f744844bec21ac04) on the official forums:

> ...the character is already Incapacitated when the roll is made, which
>   means Berserk has ended. They either need the Edges Hard to Kill to
>   ignore the penalties [to the Vigor roll to avoid death] entirely or
>   Nerves of Steel (/Improved) to ignore them partially.

In other words, **incapacitation stops the character being berserk**. No need for those pesky Smart rolls at -2, just be hit hard enough. ;-)